# recover GIT repository after HDD crash

Tags: git, version-control

Linux Magrathea 3.6.11+ #474 PREEMPT Thu Jun 13 17:14:42 BST 2013 armv6l GNU/Linux
on Raspberry. Works as GIT Server.Repositories have no branches.
I´m a beginner with git but I love it!

I was able to recover some data using `fsck` and found git objects in `Lost-Found`. After reading some threads here I did the following:

- Create a new empty git repository: `git init`
- Copy all objects to new repository `.git/objects`
- run `git fsck --full`

No bad errors.

But if I try to do `git log` I get

> fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'

What is the next step? How to reconnect the last state?

If I try to clone the repository using: `git clone git@magrathea:/gitroot/chorus`. I get back that the repository is empty.

I'm sorry but I'm a simple user of Git. I do not known something about the internal organization of git.

Please be so kind and provide me some tips.

Comment: So why has this been voted as off-topic? faq states stackoverflow is about "software tools commonly used by programmers", and there has been a wealth of cases where it has been determined that vcs usage is on-topic for stackoverflow. Voting for reopening.

Comment: @user3503533 in the future, it may be wise to keep copies of your repo on different devices, so that if one device fails, you can just clone a new copy from one of the other devices.

Answer (score 2):

You get that message when `HEAD` refers to something that doesn't exist.  When you do `git init`, `HEAD` is usually attached to the `master` branch -- which you haven't committed any revisions to yet. Thus: "bad default revision" here means "*no*" default revision.

So look at `.git/logs/refs/heads/master` in the repo you recovered the objects from, you want the second word (`awk {print $2;exit}` the file).  In the repo you're constructing,

> `git update-ref -m "reconstructing the repo" refs/heads/master`*`that_sha`*.

Now, as I recall, `git fsck` chases refs, and you don't have any yet, so its staying silent probably didn't mean much.  Good luck.

(edit: `git branch master`*`that_sha`* would probably work as well...)